# Django calling model save twice producing index error

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following code for generating thumbnail.

```
def make_thumbnail(dst_image_field, src_image_field, size, name_suffix, sep='_'):
    """
    make thumbnail image and field from source image field

    @example
        thumbnail(self.thumbnail, self.image, (200, 200), 'thumb')
    """
    # create thumbnail image
    image = PImage.open(src_image_field)
    image.thumbnail(size, PImage.ANTIALIAS)

    # build file name for dst
    dst_path, dst_ext = os.path.splitext(src_image_field.name)
    dst_ext = dst_ext.lower()
    dst_fname = dst_path + sep + name_suffix + dst_ext

    # check extension
    if dst_ext in ['.jpg', '.jpeg']:
        filetype = 'JPEG'
    elif dst_ext == '.gif':
        filetype = 'GIF'
    elif dst_ext == '.png':
        filetype = 'PNG'
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('unrecognized file type of "%s"' % dst_ext)

    # Save thumbnail to in-memory file as StringIO
    dst_bytes = BytesIO()
    image.save(dst_bytes, filetype)
    dst_bytes.seek(0)

    # set save=False, otherwise it will run in an infinite loop
    dst_image_field.save(dst_fname, ContentFile(dst_bytes.read()), save=False)
    dst_bytes.close()

class Image(models.Model):
    path = models.ImageField(upload_to=photo_image_upload_path,blank=False, null=False)
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to='', editable=False, default=None, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # save for image
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print("#1")

        ext = self.path.name.split('.')[-1]

        make_thumbnail(self.thumb, self.path, (150, 150), 'thumb')
        print("#2")

        # save for thumbnail and icon
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print("#3")
```

This leads to the output:

```
#1
#2 
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "media_image_pkey" 
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(7) already exists.
```

The image is uploaded to this model through a primary model and references this by FK so I'm assuming it's somehow trying to generate two PKs on the second save?

Comment: can you check what `*args` and `**kwargs` are here?

Comment: args = ()
kwargs = {'force_insert': True, 'using': 'default'}